# Applying CQRS to Inventory Management

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am still trying to wrap my head around how to apply DDD and, most recently, CQRS to a real production business application.  In my case, I am working on an inventory management system.  It runs as a server-based application exposed via a REST API to several client applications.  My focus has been on the domain layer with the API and clients to follow.

The command side of the domain is used to create a new Order and allows modifications, cancellation, marking an Order as fulfilled and shipped/completed.  I, of course, have a query that returns a list of orders in the system (as read-only, lightweight DTOs) from the repository.  Another query returns a PickList used by warehouse employees to pull items from the shelves to fulfill specific orders.  In order to create the PickList, there are calculations, rules, etc that must be evaluated to determine which orders are ready to be fulfilled.  For example, if all order line items are in stock.  I need to read the same list of orders, iterate over the list and apply those rules and calculations to determine which items should be included in the PickList.

This is not a simple query, so how does it fit into the model?

**UPDATE**

While I may be able to maintain (store) a set of PickLists, they really are dynamic until an employee retrieves the next PickList.  Consider the following scenario:

*The first Order of the day is received. I can raise a domain event that triggers an AssemblePickListCommand which applies all of the rules and logic to create one or more PickLists for that Order.*

*A second Order is received.  The event handler should now REPLACE the original PickLists with one or more new PickLists optimized across both pending Orders.*

*Likewise after a third Order is received.*

*Let's assume we now have two PickLists in the 'queue' because the optimization rules split the lists because components are at opposite ends of the warehouse.*

*Warehouse employee #1 requests a PickList.  The first PickList is pulled and printed.*

*A fourth Order is received. As before, the handler removes the second PickList from the queue (the only one remaining) and regenerates one or more PickLists based on the second PickList and the new Order.*

*The PickList 'assembler' will repeat this logic whenever a new Order is received.*

My issue with this is that a request must either block while the PickList queue is being updated or I have an eventual consistency issue that goes against the behavior the customer wants. Each time they request a PickList, they want it optimized based on all of the Order received to that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

> While I may be able to maintain (store) a set of PickLists, they really are dynamic until an employee retrieves the next PickList. Consider the following scenario:
>
> The first Order of the day is received. I can raise a domain event that triggers an AssemblePickListCommand which applies all of the rules and logic to create one or more PickLists for that Order.
>
> A second Order is received. The event handler should now REPLACE the original PickLists with one or more new PickLists optimized across both pending Orders.

This sounds to me like you are getting tangled trying to use a language that doesn't actually match the domain you are working in.

In particular, I don't believe that you would be having these modeling problems if the PickList "queue" was a real thing.  I think instead there is an OrderItem collection that lives inside some aggregate, you issue commands to that aggregate to generate a PickList.

That is, I would expect a flow that looks like

```
onOrderPlaced(List<OrderItems> items)
    warehouse.reserveItems(List<OrderItems> items)
        // At this point, the items are copied into an unasssigned
        // items collection.  In other words, the aggregate knows
        // that the items have been ordered, and are not currently
        // assigned to any picklist
        fire(ItemsReserved(items))

onPickListRequested(Id<Employee> employee)
    warehouse.assignPickList(Id<Employee> employee, PickListOptimizier optimizer)
         // PickListOptimizer is your calculation, rules, etc that know how
         // to choose the right items to put into the next pick list from a
         // a given collection of unassigned items.  This is a stateless domain
         // *domain service* -- it provides the query that the warehouse aggregate needs
         // to figure out the right change to make, but it *doesn't* change
         // the state of the aggregate -- that's the aggregate's responsibility

        List<OrderItems> pickedItems = optimizer.chooseItems(this.unassignedItems);
        this.unassignedItems.removeAll(pickedItems);

        // This mockup assumes we can consider PickLists to be entities
        // within the warehouse aggregate.  You'd need some additional
        // events if you wanted the PickList to have its own aggregate
        Id<PickList> = PickList.createId(...);
        this.pickLists.put(id, new PickList(id, employee, pickedItems))
        fire(PickListAssigned(id, employee, pickedItems);

onPickListCompleted(Id<PickList> pickList)
    warehouse.closePicklist(Id<PickList> pickList)
        this.pickLists.remove(pickList)
        fire(PickListClosed(pickList)

onPickListAbandoned(Id<PickList> pickList)
    warehouse.reassign(Id<PickList> pickList)
        PickList list = this.pickLists.remove(pickList)
        this.unassignedItems.addAll(list.pickedItems)
        fire(ItemsReassigned(list.pickedItems)
```

Not great languaging -- I don't speak warehouse.  But it covers most of your points: each time a new PickList is generated, it's being built from the latest state of pending items in the warehouse.

There's some contention - you can't assign items to a pick list AND change the unassigned items at the same time.  Those are two different writes to the same aggregate, and I don't think you are going to get around that as long as the client insists upon a perfectly optimized picklist each time.  It might be worth while to sit down with the domain experts and explore the real cost to the business if the second best pick list is assigned from time to time.  After all, there's already latency between the placing the order and its arrival at the warehouse....

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what your specific question is. But the first thing that comes to mind is that pick list creation is not just a query but a full blown business concept that should be explicitly modeled. It then could be created with `AssemblePicklist` command for instance.

Comment: In what I have read, by their nature, commands are one-way. In other words, I haven't seen any examples or read a description of commands being used in this manner.  I know it's possible, just not something I've seen discussed.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. The `Assemble Picklist` command and its usage wouldn't differ from any other command. There probably is some misunderstanding here. What exactly do you mean with "commands being used in this manner"?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't receive an alert that you had commented.

Comment: What I mean is that every example I've seen and all of the material I've read treat commands as one-way operations. In other words, they don't return data.

Comment: Do you use commands to encapsulate your queries as well as to perform work with your domain objects?

Comment: @SonOfPirate I'm not saying that the command should return anything. I was thinking of a `AssemblePicklist` command that would trigger the creation and storage of an AggregateRoot `Picklist`. Which in turn can be received using a query. That's what I mean with explicitly modelling the concept of a `Picklist` and its creation.

Comment: Hmmm.  What in your mind would trigger the command to create and store the PickList if not the request? The process I am modeling is pretty well established with the warehouse employee generating a picklist, pulling the items, then returning to generate another picklist, etc. There can be multiple employees doing this and each picklist is generated based on the current state of the orders in the system at the time.

Comment: @SonOfPirate I'm afraid we're talking past each other and we probably won't be able to clarify what we mean through this commenting function. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two roles/processes and possibly also two aggregate roots - salesperson works with orders, warehouse worker with picklists.

`AssemblePicklistsCommand()` is triggered from order processing and recreates all currently unassigned picklists.

Warehouse worker fires a `AssignPicklistCommand(userid)` which tries to choose the most appropriate unassigned picklist and assign it to him (or doing nothing if he already has an active picklist). He could then use `GetActivePicklistQuery(userid)` to get the picklist, pick items with `PickPicklistItemCommand(picklistid, item, quantity)` and finally `MarkPicklistCompleteCommand()` to signal order he's done.

AssemblePicklist and AssignPicklist should block each other (serial processing, optimistic concurency?) but the relation between AssignPicklist and GetActivePicklist is clean - either you have a picklist assigned or you don't.